# PHP/Mysql Query by readable time

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

Im using codeigniter and somewhere along the way I guess we setup a php_errors db or its something that codeigniter does automatically. Anyways there is no timestamps in this db all there is is a time column that reads out like this : 2015-10-04 01:22:0

[image]

Id like to query for any errors that occured in the last 5 minutes but have no idea where to begin when its based off human readable time like this

Comment: see [str_to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php)

Comment: and what is wrong with 2015-10-04 01:22:0 ??

Comment: Do you tried anything. Search over the internet about this question, you will surely get the answer

Comment: human readable date-time is far better than timestamp

Comment: Search this in the internet. Date function in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use the date_sub function

```
$date = date_create('2015-10-04 01:22:0');
date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('5 minutes'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

link to date_sub function on PHP website

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

if you want to do this in mysql you can use SUBTIME()

this is just an example not sure if it works

```
SELECT SUBTIME(time,'1 1:1:5.0'); FROM TABLE_NAME
```

SUBTIME() on mysql site

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime